# IIS gZip Compression Not Working event after Setting Everything

Tags: ajax, iis, compression, gzip, content-encoding

I deployed a simple html page with ajax (loading a json file) in my iis 8.0 (windows 8) and iis7+ (windows 7). 
1. I enabled static and dynamic compression in IIS
2. I have written all the tags in we.config and the same has been attached.
Still I am not getting content-encoded: gZip in response header.

webconfig is like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
      <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
      <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
      <!-- in the case of .html files; if you AJAX load html files (i.e. in angular) then remove these two lines. -->
      <remove fileExtension=".html" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
      <remove fileExtension=".js" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <!-- HTML5 Audio/Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".mp3" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
      <!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <!-- HTML4 Web font mime types -->
      <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".crx" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xpi" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
      <remove fileExtension=".safariextz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <!-- Flash Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".flv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
      <remove fileExtension=".f4v" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <!-- Assorted types -->
      <remove fileExtension=".ico" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
      <remove fileExtension=".htc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
      <remove fileExtension=".vcf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
      <remove fileExtension=".torrent" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent" />
      <remove fileExtension=".cur" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webapp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8" />
    </staticContent>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="test.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ever resolve this one?